# How to make .print() macro use F() by default (Arduino)

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I usually use base(hardware's UART) serial communication for debugging during development.
This means that most of the text snend to print() will not be send in a final product (limited to repair level only messages). 
with mine debugging messages being of a considerable info with loot of tabs and stated variables (and their descriptions), I find that mine 1K5 lined project spends several times more RAM on debugging messages then on program itself. 
With one letter being one byte 2000 letters is nothing.

Most of mine non-debugging serial communication (during development is using software serial Tx) and using write function, works with bytes themselves and does not send actual text. (currently mine serial communication routine function  and structure uses 6 byte blocks including addressing).

To the point: I use Streaming.h to speed the text addition to serial sending.
It is annoying to keep putting Text strings into F() every single time
F() Function slows the operation of the device because rather then Globally wasting RAM it reads it from flash every time its used and without it mine debuging messages use too much SRAM (arduino loads them as a global variables)

**Is there a way of making print() use F() function without editing the Wire.h library ?** (which would block me from being able to automatically update the header files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `F()` to store you text in FLASH memory, you can't avoid this.

You can define the macro:

```
#define FPRINT(x) print(F(x))

Serial.FPRINT("text");
```

Or even like that:

```
#define SFPRINT(x) Serial.print(F(x))

SFPRINT("test");
```

Of course, you can replace `FPRINT` with anything you want, that is not pre-defined (in this case you will get compiler warning).

You can also use [`printf_P`](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdio_1ga418e63921ed6259e873cd21b6c5c8e6e.html) function from `<stdio.h>` and [`PSTR`](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__pgmspace_1ga05ca900ebf7cd121be73c654d9ccb3eb.html) macro from `<avr/pgmspace.h>` (they should in included by default to you program in Arduino IDE).

Typical use with text stored in RAM:

```
int a = 5;
printf("This is my variable: %d", a);
```

Result:

```
Sketch uses 1946 bytes (6%) of program storage space.
Global variables use 39 bytes (1%) of dynamic memory
```

Use with text stored in FLASH:

```
int a = 5;
printf_P(PSTR ("This is my variable: %d"), a);
```

Result:

```
Sketch uses 1958 bytes (6%) of program storage space.
Global variables use 15 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory
```

Comment: I am in a hospital and will test it soon. I definitely like the idea of PHP like print
I wonder if it would be possible to do something like:
 ' #define PPRINT(x,y)  printf_P(PSTR ("x"), y)'
I am new to macros

Comment: @Tomas No, but you can do this: `#define PPRINT(x,y) printf_P(PSTR(x),y)` and then `PPRINT("test %d", a);`  Don't include `;` at the end of macro define. By the way, you can do even something like this: `#define SFPRINT(x) Serial.print(F(x))` and then `SFPRINT("test");`

Comment: @Tomas By the way, I don't know if `stdout` is defined and if it is defined as serial (UART) in modern Arduino Libs (as I don't use Arduino IDE now). If not - you should define it to `printf` to serial port. You can read this doc for example: https://playground.arduino.cc/main/printf

Comment: since I haven't toughed of taking laptop with me, I still cant test it, but I wonder if it will work for multiple variables 'PPRINT("test %d second variable %s \n", a, b) '
that would make PPRINT far more practical then writing multiple steps. That would stop mine reliance on streaming library and make outpup message far more transparent.

Comment: @Tomas Yes, you can use as many variables as you want, even string variables, and put them in different formats. It's just standard C/C++ library function. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/